# SPA and Spring Boot Authentication WIth Okta

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, okta

I have an Angular SPA application and I've set up OAuth2 authentication using Okta. I also have Spring Boot Restful Web service which also requires authentication.
I followed this tutorial to do that: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/11/20/spring-data-jpa

I want to use the access token I received while logging in with the SPA to authenticate the requests sent to the Spring Boot RESTful web service. How can I do that with Okta?

Answer (score 0):

In your Rest API you need to perform these steps when an access token is received:

- Download the token signing public key from Okta's JWKS endpoint (which is then cached in your API)
- Use Spring to validate the JWT, which includes use of the public key to verify the signature

This works the same for any Authorization Server and is not Okta specific. This [online code sample](https://curity.io/resources/learn/spring-boot-api/) walks you through the steps needed in Spring - only a few lines of code are required.

Once done you then use the token's scopes and claims to enforce access to areas of your data according to your domain specific authorization rules.